# How can I use pandas to fill missing prices in my product table based on delivery dates and dates the price was given to that product?

Tags: python, pandas, datatables, data-analysis, missing-data

I have a table of products with their names, receipt dates, prices and DATE OF GIVEN PRICE.

However value of price is given only in one cell. I have to fill prices for products that were delivered after the date of given price.

What is the python code to accomplish this task using pandas? Also, I have an excel table representation of what result I want to accomplish. [MY PRODUCT TABLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OHDwo.png)

I tried to use method='ffill' however I don't know how to make "receipt date" and "date of price" to link and make all code work.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
df.groupby(['product'])['price'].transform(max)
```